# Heroku - Node.js application deployed successfully, heroku local fails

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a MEAN stack app which has been successfully deployed to heroku. Everything works great using the heroku hosted version of my application.

For some reason, when I run my app using "heroku local" it fires up and appears to be working correctly but I can't access any of my endpoints.

Postman gives me the following error instantly "Could not get any response". I am also at a loss for where to even begin troubleshooting this problem, even running the application using "node app.js" gives me the same error. This did not happen prior to deploying to heroku!

Some files I have added are 'Procfile'

```
web: node app.js
```

Am I missing something here?

Another thing I have added is the MongoLab addon, to isolate and see if this was the issue I created a test endpoint at "http://localhost:8080/api/test" but it doesnt even respond with the simple "message: 'Success!'" json response.

Comment: have you set all of your environmental variables?

Comment: To match the ones on heroku? Yes, I have them matching and have confirmed.